# git rebase -i shortcut -- finding the best commit to rebase on

Tags: git, version-control, git-rebase, git-interactive-rebase

### Summary

What is the fastest way of finding, in the current branch, the most recent commit also contained in any other branches?

**Bonus:** Can the technique allow for "any other branches" in the question above to be "any other remote branches" or "any other local branches"?

---

### Background

I love using `git rebase -i`. My main use case for it is to re-organize commits before pushing to remote. Thus, I often do `git rebase -i origin/master`. So I've set up an alias to that operation called `git rewrite`.

The issue is that I don't always want to rebase against `origin/master`. For example, I may be working on a branch and instead want `git rewrite` to do `git rebase -i origin/branch`. Or I may be working a local branch and want `git rewrite` to do `git rebase -i localbranch`.

So in effect, I'm trying to make my `git rewrite` script do something like: "do an interactive rebase from the last commit contained in any other branch". What I've come up with is this: (which only works for finding remote branches)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Do a git rebase -i from the most recent common point between the
# current branch and any other remote branch.

# We go backwards in the branch's history and for each commit check if
# that commit is present in one of the remote branches. As soon as we
# find one that is, we stop and rebase on that.

commit=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
while [ true ]; do
   branch=$(git branch -r --contains $commit)
   if [ -n "$branch" ]; then
      # This commit exists in another remote branch!
      break
   fi
   # OK, let's try the previous commit
   commit=$(git log --pretty=%P -n 1 $commit)
   # Stupid heuristic, take only first commit if multiple parents
   commit=${commit%% *}
done

git rebase -i $commit
```

The problem with this method is that it's **slow**. It's also a bit inaccurate since it follows only one of the parents when a commit has multiple parents.

Does anyone know a better/faster/cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rewrite script might look like this (bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
for rev in $(git rev-list HEAD); do
    num=$(git branch --all --contains ${rev} | wc | awk '{print $1}')
    [ ${num} -eq 1 ] || break
    count=$(( count + 1 ))
done
if [ ${count} -gt 0 ]; then
    git rebase -i HEAD~${count}
fi
```

What I do a lot of times instead is (rebase from upstream point):

```
git rebase -i @{u}
```

The `@{u}` technique does not catch other branches however.

Comment: It's true that `@{u}` only works with the one upstream, but you can set the upstream for a local branch based off another local branch, by just setting the "remote" for it to `.` (note: `git branch --set-upstream-to` knows how to do this for you, so just set the upstream to the local branch).  This is usually the way to go, especially since `git rebase -i` with no upstream argument will automatically use `@{u}`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads --format='git merge-base %(refname) yourbranch' \
| sh >merge-bases
git log --first-parent --format='%H %s' \
| grep -f merge-bases -
```

`refs/heads` is the "any local branches" version, add or substitute `refs/remotes` for remote branches.

Process substitution apparently doesn't mix with pipelines on windows, on linux you can avoid the temporary file that way.

(edit: aaaannd the grep there's backlevel too, dumb that down)

Comment: Both answers were great, but I picked the other one because it runs slightly faster. I did learn a lot from your answer though! :)